# Excluding existed users in the ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I am building a small BlogApp and I build a feature of adding favorite users. User can search and add the user in his favorite users list

I am now building a feature `if searched user is already in another's users favorite user list then exclude the user from the result`

> For example :- If user_1 added user_50 in his favorite user's list. and then if user_2 searched user_50 then it will not show in the search list.

BUT when i try to exclude then it is not excluding.

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,unique=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')
    friends = models.ManyToManyField("Profile",blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=60,default='')

class FavouriteUsers(models.Model):
    adder = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    favouriteUser = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='favouriteUser', blank=True)
```

views.py

```
def search_users_favourite(request):
    q = request.GET.get('q')
    exclude_this = FavouriteUsers.objects.filter(favouriteUser=request.user)

    results = Profile.objects.filter(user__username__icontains=q).exclude(exclude_this)
    serialized_results = []
    for result in results:
        serialized_results.append({
            'id': result.id,
            'username': result.user.username,
        })

    return JsonResponse({'results': serialized_results})
```

BUT this is showing :-

> TypeError: Cannot filter against a non-conditional expression.

I have tried many times but it is still that error.

Any help would be Appreciated.

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: Can you show the profile model

Comment: @bdbd Updated the Profile Model in the Question

Comment: Try this: `Profile.objects.filter(user__username__icontains=q).exclude(user__in=exclude_this.values('favouriteUser')`

Comment: It is still showing the user in search results

Comment: Wait I got it, try this: `Profile.objects.filter(user__username__icontains=q, user__ favouriteUser__isnull=True)`

Comment: It is still showing the user which is already in another user's favorite list

Comment: @bdbd, It is now working. Thank You Very Much bdbd for your Help. Thanks. AND You can also post it as an `Answer`.

Comment: Ok I added it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```
Profile.objects.filter(user__username__icontains=q, user__favouriteUser__isnull=True)
```

This will exclude all profiles that are already mapped in `FavouriteUsers` (already has been a favorite)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be doing it this way

`exclude_this = FavouriteUsers.objects.filter(favouriteUser=request.user).values_list('favouriteUser__username',flat=True)`

`results = Profile.objects.filter(user__username__icontains=q).exclude(user__username__in=exclude_this)`  here, i assume you want to exclude usernames matching the entire name.

For a better answer, please attach the log of the error.

Comment: It didn't work. AND It is showing `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: operator does not exist: character varying = integer
LINE 1: ...KE UPPER('%asd%') AND NOT ("auth_user"."username" IN (SELECT...` in the terminal

Comment: can you share me the entire log Van? and the inputs you provided.

Comment: It says `    `return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: operator does not exist: character varying = integer
LINE 1: ...KE UPPER('%asd%') AND NOT ("auth_user"."username" IN (SELECT...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`
AND i searched username of user using ajax

Answer (score 0):

I spent hours tearing my hair out over this issue, so I wanted to post a quick response here on *what* is actually causing this exception:

The problem is this (pseudo code):

```py
query = Model.objects.filter(something=value)
result = Model.objects.filter(query).first()
```

This won't work (apparently). Django hates it big time.

**The problem is that you can't pass a QuerySet to `filter` or `exclude`**.

Instead, use your QuerySet directly:

```
query = Model.objects.filter(something=value)
result = query.first()
```